# WCF: Error the recipient of this message did not understand the "Security" header

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have created a WCF service and send a request to the service through soapUI I get an error in response:

```
The header 'Security' from the namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding
```

Tell me, please, how to properly set the security header?

Most likely I need to process the signature, but I don’t know how to do it. I didn't find any information on how to do this.

Here is my request:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                       xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34310-gost34311"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="test">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34311"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>test</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>
                    test
                </ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <wsse:KeyIdentifier
                                EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
                                ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">
                            test
                        </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <S:Body xmlns:ns2="http://bip.bee.kz/SyncChannel/v10/Types"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            wsu:Id="test">
        <ns2:SendMessage>
            <request>
                <requestInfo>
                    <test>test</test>
                    <sender>
                        <test>test</test>
                    </sender>
                    <sessionId>test</sessionId>
                </requestInfo>
                <requestData>
                    <data>
                        <test>test</test>
                    </data>
                </requestData>
            </request>
        </ns2:SendMessage>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Service.svc processing the request:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string SendMessage(SendMessage request)
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Model:

```
[MessageContract(WrapperName="SendMessage", IsWrapped=true, WrapperNamespace = "")]
public class SendMessage
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "", Name = "request")]
    public Request Request { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlType(Namespace = "")]
public class Request
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "requestInfo", Order = 0)]
    public RequestInfo RequestInfo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "requestData", Order = 1)]
    public RequestData RequestData { get; set; }
}
```

Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

If you specify verification using a certificate:

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"
        name="Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding"
          name="ConclusionService" contract="IService" />
      </service>
    </services>
 
     <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
         
            <serviceCertificate findValue="test" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
 
<customBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBinding">
          <security authenticationMode="AnonymousForCertificate" requireDerivedKeys="false"
            messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Warning: 'Message with action '' has no message signature parts specified.'

Answer (score 0):

You can view WS-Security header block in the Raw section, but before going there make some changes and resend request.

[image: Image showing where the performance button is.]

To use X.509 certificates, you need to set it up on the server side like this:

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="xxxxx" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
```

At the same time, the certificate's encodevalue authentication is used on the client：

```
<identity>
<certificate encodevalue="xxxx"/>
</identity>
```